# Traversing a graph of flowchart in python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, traversal, flowchart, graphml

I have a flow chart for implementing some rules in our product. Nodes consists of rules & decisions including start and end node in every flowchart. Using networkx package of python, I got graphml of flowchart. Now, I want to traverse a graph in such a way that traversal should be same as flow of flowchart.
Here is the image of flow chart.
[Flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDEhw.png)

I'm up for further further clarifications in my question, if anyone needed

Comment: Have you tried to do it? What exact issues did you face?

Comment: Yes I have tried using different traversal functions of networkx. But the link between nodes is not consistent. e.g if arrow head from node1 is facing to node2 the tuple representation is (node1 , node2). But in some cases it shows (node2 , node1). Specifically in the case of 'END'  node. There is not forward arrow from 'END' node, because ideally every end node has only in-arrows. But in this case function is returning tuple of end node with connected node in reverse order. I hope you could understand.